# ¿Cómo podría obtener únicamente los 6 primeros caracteres de una variable mandado por $_POST?

Tags: php, html, formularios

Holaa, estoy intentando hacer que si un input coincide exactamente con uno de mis valores de array les redirija a otro sitio, para eso he de tomar únicamente los 6 primeros dígitos de los mandados vía post. El problema es que el código que he escrito no ha funcionado, la cookie `dependency` adquiere el valor de `Generali` no el de `supa`. Dejo aquí el código:

PHP

```
    $cda = $data['kod']['name'];  //Variable obtenida a través de llamada a la API
    $numa = $_POST['codi']; // Variable obtenida de formulario
        $worktt = str_split($numa, 6);
    $tsim_array = [
    "411111", "411112"
    ];
    
    if (in_array($worktt, $tsim_array)) {
        $cda = "supa";
    }
    else{
    
    }
    $supa_array = [
    "supa"
];
    if (in_array($cda, $supa_array)) {
        $val = "supa";
    $paqui = "3";
    setcookie('dependency', $val, time()+47375753, '/');   //this cookie will work as parameter in the case that the user leaves the web.
    setcookie('wi', $paqui, time()+384738493, '/' );
    }
    else{
    $val = "Generali";
    $paqui = "3";
    setcookie('dependency', $val, time()+47375753, '/');   //this cookie will work as parameter in the case that the user leaves the web.
    setcookie('wi', $paqui, time()+384738493, '/' ); // this works as last step.
    }
```

Comment: Intenta con `if (in_array($worktt[0], $tsim_array)) {`

Comment: Ahora si funciona, pero, ¿me podrías explicar por qué es así? Gracias de antemani @alanfcm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema esta en esta linea:

```
if (in_array($worktt, $tsim_array)) {
```

La funcion `str_split` divide una cadena y devuelve un array.  Entonces en la linea

```
$worktt = str_split($numa, 6);
```

la variable `$worktt` contiene un array.  El resultado que buscas esta en la primera posicion del array.  La forma correcta de comparar seria asi:

```
if (in_array($worktt[0], $tsim_array)) {
```